Why Does void *p = &&aa; Compile Even When the Code for Label aa Is Optimized Away Due to a goto Statement?
In C language, I want to obtain the address of a label, and I found the following method:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html
However, due to the presence of a goto statement in my code, a strange thing happened:
https://godbolt.org/z/P88MrY5re
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    void *p = &&aa;
    printf("hello, never execute\n");
    goto end; 
aa:
    printf("new path\n");
end:
    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}

and this is the assemble code:
.LC0:
        .string "hello, never execute"
.LC1:
        .string "end"
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
.L2:
        movq    $.L2, -8(%rbp)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        nop
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        call    puts
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret

When I commented out the goto statement, I correctly obtained the address of label aa:
https://godbolt.org/z/P88MrY5re
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    void *p = &&aa;
    printf("hello, never execute\n");
    //goto end; 
aa:
    printf("new path\n");
end:
    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}

.LC0:
        .string "hello, never execute"
.LC1:
        .string "new path"
.LC2:
        .string "end"
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movq    $.L2, -8(%rbp)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
.L2:
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        call    puts
        movl    $.LC2, %edi
        call    puts
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret

Therefore, I want to know if the compiler has already removed label aa when there's a goto statement. I feel that the code void *p = &&aa; shouldn't compile. Is this a bug in gcc, or is there something I haven't considered?
I've looked up some information and asked people around me, but I haven't gotten the answer I wanted. I want to know if this counts as a bug in gcc, or could you provide some resources or ideas for me?
Thank you, everyone!

Why shouldn't it compile? You never use the variable, so it doesn't matter what value is put there.

Optimization doesn't change the observable behavior of the code.  In particular, whether or not code compiles is independent of how it's optimized.

@Barmar Thank you very much! I tried adding a statement goto *p at the end label, and I found that p correctly obtained the address of label aa.

In fact, I discovered this code while studying overflow attacks. What I wanted to do was obtain the address of label aa, then use strcpy to modify the function's stack frame and overwrite its return address. This way, when a function returns, it would start executing code from aa. However, I found that due to the goto statement, the variable p holds the address of the main function, which prevented me from succeeding.

While the compiler did optimize away the call to printf("new path\n");, it didn't completely remove everything.  You'll notice after the first call puts instruction is a nop.  This is the instruction that the label points to.
Also, if code failed to compile due to an optimization being turned on, a case could be made that the optimizer has a bug, as optimizations shouldn't affect the observable behavior of the code.

Thank for your answer.However, I still have a question:  Why does it generate movq $.L2, -8(%rbp)? Shouldn't it assign the address of a nop instruction to p?And, when I compile with clang, I found it generates movq $1, -16(%rbp)https://godbolt.org/z/KcYE5vxYa. If I later use the value of p, it would definitely lead to an error. But with gcc, it stores the address of an instruction, even though it's not what we want. I still think this is unreasonable.

it will compile differently if you actually use p. @吃花椒的喵酱

Thank you very much for your response! I think I understand what you mean. This is actually an issue of compiler optimization. As you mentioned earlier, as long as the program's behavior doesn't change, such optimization is permissible. After all, since I didn't use the value of variable p, it doesn't matter what it holds.
However, if p could store the address of the nop instruction, I think that might be a better option than storing the address of the main function.Once again, I want to express my gratitude to you all.@Barmar
